# How to add an image by using MYSQL insert command into a table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Movie
(Movie_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Movie_Image BLOB NOT NULL,
 Movie_Name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Movie_Description TEXT,
 Movie_Genre VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Movie_Rating VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Movie_Duration INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Movie_ID)
 )
```

Then I tried inserting the following values:

```
INSERT INTO Movie (Movie_Image, Movie_Name, Movie_Description, Movie_Genre, Movie_Rating, Movie_Duration)
VALUES (LOAD_FILE('E:/justice league.jpg'),'Justice League','Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Supermans selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists newfound ally Diana Prince to face an even greater threat. Together, Batman and Wonder Woman work quickly to recruit a team to stand against this newly awakened enemy. Despite the formation of an unprecedented league of heroes','Action','PG-13',120); 
INSERT INTO Movie (Movie_Image, Movie_Name, Movie_Description, Movie_Genre, Movie_Rating, Movie_Duration)
VALUES (LOAD_FILE('E:/thor.jpg'),'Thor: Ragnarok','Imprisoned on the other side of the universe, the mighty Thor finds himself in a deadly gladiatorial contest that pits him against the Hulk, his former ally and fellow Avenger. Thors quest for survival leads him in a race against time to prevent the all-powerful Hela from destroying his home world and the Asgardian civilization.','Action','PG-13',130); 
INSERT INTO Movie (Movie_Image, Movie_Name, Movie_Description, Movie_Genre, Movie_Rating, Movie_Duration)
VALUES (LOAD_FILE('E:/star wars.jpg'),'Star Wars: The Last Jedi','Luke Skywalkers peaceful and solitary existence gets upended when he encounters Rey, a young woman who shows strong signs of the Force. Her desire to learn the ways of the Jedi forces Luke to make a decision that changes their lives forever.','Action','PG-13',152);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
#1048 - Column 'Movie_Image' cannot be null
```

How to insert the image in the table by INSERT command in MYSQL ?
It would be really helpful if the solution code is provided.

Comment: If you run the INSERTS individually, do they all give you the same error?

Comment: I tried running the INSERTS individually and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table, declare size of BLOB column as :

```
CREATE TABLE test ( ... Movie_Image BLOB, INDEX(Movie_Image(100)), ...);
```

then, your insert :

```
INSERT INTO Movie (Movie_Image, Movie_Name, Movie_Description, Movie_Genre, Movie_Rating, Movie_Duration)
VALUES (LOAD_FILE('E:/justice league.jpg'),'Justice League','Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Supermans selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists newfound ally Diana Prince to face an even greater threat. Together, Batman and Wonder Woman work quickly to recruit a team to stand against this newly awakened enemy. Despite the formation of an unprecedented league of heroes','Action','PG-13',120),
(LOAD_FILE('E:/thor.jpg'),'Thor: Ragnarok','Imprisoned on the other side of the universe, the mighty Thor finds himself in a deadly gladiatorial contest that pits him against the Hulk, his former ally and fellow Avenger. Thors quest for survival leads him in a race against time to prevent the all-powerful Hela from destroying his home world and the Asgardian civilization.','Action','PG-13',130),
(LOAD_FILE('E:/star wars.jpg'),'Star Wars: The Last Jedi','Luke Skywalkers peaceful and solitary existence gets upended when he encounters Rey, a young woman who shows strong signs of the Force. Her desire to learn the ways of the Jedi forces Luke to make a decision that changes their lives forever.','Action','PG-13',152);
```

You can call a single INSERT INTO (columns) VALUES statement, then write each values between parenthesis ( ) with comma between them.

Comment: I tried all of them which you have suggested and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @beginIT, I modified the answer and checked the query. Now, must be right.

Comment: I tried your single INSERT INTO statement right now. But, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: how I said first time, try to insert another image without space in name (as: E:/justice league.jpg)

Comment: I just now tried again by inserting another image without space in name as E:/justiceleague.jpg  and I also renamed the original file from justice league.jpg to justiceleague.jpg. But, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe this will help: For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index prefix length. As you specified the size for varchar, need to specify as for blob

Comment: Can you give one example regarding specification of index prefix length for BLOB ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164114/discussion-between-allexys-and-beginit).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

*LOAD FILE*

Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

**If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.**

1. Check the file exists on the server, in the location provided.
2. Check your MySQL user has FILE privs.
3. Check the file is readable by all.
4. Check the size of the max_allowed_packet bytes - and make sure it's large enough to accommodate your files.
5. Check whether or not the secure_file_priv is set. If it is, you need to load the files from that directory.